# Parser identifiers and free format text. Can this be done with FParsec?

Tags: f#, fparsec

As a follow-on to: [How do I test for exactly 2 characters with fparsec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525975/how-do-i-test-for-exactly-2-characters-with-fparsec)

I need to parse a string that consists of pairs of identifiers followed by freeform text. I can easily construct a parser that finds the identifiers which are of the form of newline followed by exactly two uppercase characters followed by a space. The freeform text, which is associated with the preceding identifier, is everything following the identifier up to but not including the next identifier.

So for example:

```
AB Now is the
time for all good
men.
CD Four score and seven years ago EF our.
```

contains two identifiers `AB` and `CD` and two pieces of freeform text

`Now is the \ntime for all good men.`
`Four score and seven years ago EF our.`

My problem is I don't know how to construct a parser that would match the freeform text but not match the identifiers. Is this a case where I need to do backtracking?

Can this be done and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `notFollowedBy` is what you're looking for. This should do the trick:

```
// adapted from the other question
let identifier = skipNewline >>. manyMinMaxSatisfy 2 2 CharParsers.isUpper

let freeform = manyChars (notFollowedBy identifier >>. anyChar)
```

Answer (score 4):

Tarmil posted the straightforward solution.

Here's another variant, which doesn't need a newline at the beginning and which checks for a following identifier only at the end of lines:

```
let id = manyMinMaxSatisfyL 2 2 isUpper "ID" .>> pchar ' '

let text = 
    stringsSepBy (restOfLine true) 
                 ((notFollowedBy ((id >>% ()) <|> skipNewline <|> eof)) >>% "\n")

let parser = many (id .>>. text)
```

If you wanted to optimize the second parser used with the `stringsSepBy` combinator, you could replace it with the following version:

```
let notFollowedByIdOrEmptyLineOrEof : Parser<string,_> =
    fun stream ->
        let cs = stream.Peek2()
        let c0, c1 = cs.Char0, cs.Char1
        if c0 = '\r' || c0 = '\n' || c0 = EOS
           || (isUpper c0 && isUpper c1 && stream.Peek(2) = ' ')
        then Reply(Error, NoErrorMessages)
        else Reply("\n")

let text2 = stringsSepBy (restOfLine true) 
                         notFollowedByIdOrEmptyLineOrEof
```

Comment: Hi, could you please comment on this question: https://bitbucket.org/fparsec/main/issue/29/portable-version-of-fparsec